# Why can I not password protect specific URL paths?

Tags: server, apache2, password

I have a directory that I would like only real users to access.

That directory is [www.example.com/video](http://www.example.com/video)

I have gone into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and made sure that the following was set:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then I entered into the path /var/www/example.com/public_html/video and created the following .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/passwd
Require valid-user
```

I realize the passwd file seems in a strange place, according to other posts I have looked at. But when I cat it, it has all passwords, including test users I created today.

I get the proper popup,

Yet it won't accept any users and their passwords. The web page I get, once I give up and click cancel is:

> Unauthorized
>
> This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the
> document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g.,
> bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
> credentials required.
>
> Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) Port 80

Any thoughts as to what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: `AuthUserFile /etc/passwd`? `/etc/passwd` certainly isn't in [the htpasswd format](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html).

Comment: My problem is now solved. I'll have to open another ticket to find out where my SSH users are stored, and regular users.... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but you do need to follow the [rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_file.html) as described:

> The AuthUserFile directive sets the name of a textual file containing the list of users and passwords for user authentication. File-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the ServerRoot.
>
> Each line of the user file contains a username followed by a colon, followed by the encrypted password.
>
> For mod_auth_basic, use the utility htpasswd which is installed as part of the binary distribution, or which can be found in src/support. See the man page for more details. In short:
>
> - Create a password file Filename with username as the initial ID. It will prompt for the password:
>
>   ```
>   htpasswd -c Filename username
>   ```
> - Add or modify username2 in the password file Filename:
>
>   ```
>   htpasswd Filename username2
>   ```
>
> **Security**
>
> Make sure that the AuthUserFile is stored outside the document tree of the web-server. Do not put it in the directory that it protects. Otherwise, clients may be able to download the AuthUserFile.

You need to create the password file using `htpasswd`.

Comment: My problem is now solved. I'll have to open another ticket to find out where my SSH users are stored, and regular users.... Thanks for your help